# iOS UITextfield: Crashes on press of enter/return key

Tags: ios, uitextfield, newline

I am writing an app that has a form and allows you to email the form data to a computer for further editing. The form is implemented using UITextfield's, and functions correctly assuming you don't enter the "enter/return" key. If that happens, the app crashes in the simulator, or freezes on my iPad, and gives me the following message as output:

```
[FirstTableViewController hideKeyboard:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x151cb800
```

The hideKeyboard method does not exist anywhere in my code. I'm not sure at this point if it would be useful to post code, because I don't know where in the code it is happening. I tried creating an exception breakpoint, but it does not appear to be giving an information as far as where the app is crashing.

If I could get some tips on how to debug my code better, that would be great. If I get to a point where I find where the error is occurring, and can't figure it out myself, I'll update this post with the code needed.

Thanks.

Comment: "Unrecognized selector sent to instance" is a well known issue. What have you tried? There are plenty of questions on why it occurs, and how to find it. Do you have a method named "hideKeyboard:"?

Comment: What object is the 'hideKeyboard' method defined on? "Unrecognized selector" means the object that you are calling the method 'hideKeyboard' on does not have a method that matches that name. This issue most commonly occurs when you call a method on an object that you don't mean to.

Comment: I'm a bit lost because I do not have a hideKeyboard method. I don't know any other way of determining what's is wrong unless I find out where it is crashing in my code. I even did a cmd-find on my code and couldn't find any such method.

Comment: provide code fragment of handling "enter/return" key

Answer (score 2):

A nice way to debug a case like this is to add the reported unrecognized selector to the class that is being called. If it is a library class, subclass it and just add the single selector in question.

Then put a break point in the implementation, and look at the back trace when the break point is reached.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. Something I forgot to mention in my original post is that the method hideKeyboard does not exist in my code.

Comment: yes - and that is why your app is crashing. So add it and see who is calling it.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you added a selector to an event:

```
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemDone
                                                                                            target:self
                                                                                            action:@selector(hideKeyBoards)] autorelease];
```

But forgot to implement the method itself